# Calling Stored Procedures with Lots of Parameters

Tags: vba, vb6, adodb

I have this piece of code for running a Stored Procedure, and I was wondering if there is a way of cutting code like:

> ```
>    uPar = .CreateParameter("@PropertyID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
>         .Parameters.Append(uPar)
>         .Parameters("@PropertyID").Value = Val(lblPropertyIDValue.Text)
> ```

As I have a lot of stored procedures in my system this takes a lot of time, my boss seems to think there could be a way to possible cut this down to one line of code and make it a lot easier to read and write, though I'm not sure what way to go about this.

```
Public Function SaveProperty() As Boolean
    '** Save Current Personal Data Record

    ' Error Checking
    On Error GoTo Err_SaveProperty

    ' Dimension Local Variables
    Dim uRecSnap As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim uPar As ADODB.Parameter

    ' Check For Open Connection
    If uDBase Is Nothing Then
        OpenConnection()
        bConnection = True
    End If

    ' Run Stored Procedure - Save Property Record
    uCommand = New ADODB.Command
    With uCommand
        .ActiveConnection = uDBase
        .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@PropertyID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@PropertyID").Value = Val(lblPropertyIDValue.Text)
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@PropertyManager", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 60)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@PropertyManager").Value = cmbPropertyManager.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@AddressLine1", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@AddressLine1").Value = txtAddress1.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@AddressLine2", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@AddressLine2").Value = txtAddress2.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@AddressLine3", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 20)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@AddressLine3").Value = txtAddress2.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@Town", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@Town").Value = txtTown.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@PostCode", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@PostCode").Value = txtPostCode.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@Availabilty", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@Availabilty").Value = chkAvailable.Checked
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@Available", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@Available").Value = dtpAvailable.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@Factored", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@Factored").Value = -chkFactored.Checked
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@FactorsName", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 20)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@FactorsName").Value = txtFactorName.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@FactorsEmail", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@FactorsEmail").Value = txtFactorsEmail.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@PropertyBuilt", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@PropertyBuilt").Value = dtpPropertyBuilt.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@PropertyValue", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@PropertyValue").Value = txtPropertyValue.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@MimimumFee", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@MimimumFee").Value = txtMinimumFee.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@Commission", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@Commission").Value = -txtCommision.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@CostSuthorisationAmount", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 20)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@CostSuthorisationAmount").Value = txtCostAuthorisationAmount.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@Vacant", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@Vacant").Value = chkVacant.Checked
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@VacantDate", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@VacantDate").Value = dtpVacant.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@StartingRent", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@StartingRent").Value = txtStartingRent.Text

        .CommandText = "PropertyMaster_SaveRecord"

        .Execute()
    End With

    ' Close Connection
    uRecSnap = Nothing
    uCommand = Nothing
    If bConnection Then CloseConnection()
    SaveProperty = True

 Err_SaveProperty:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        sErrDescription = Err.Description
        WriteAuditLogRecord("clsProperty", "SaveProperty", "Error", sErrDescription)
        SaveProperty = False
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: vb6 sorry didnt mean net

Comment: I think this solution outlined would simplify your needs. Thanks to one of the response from stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557606/how-do-i-associate-parameters-to-command-objects-in-ado-with-vbscript

Comment: You *need* to see this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46312/creating-adodb-parameters-on-the-fly?rq=1

Comment: I've uploaded these handy classes to GitHub: https://github.com/retailcoder/VBTools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your question, then something else I noticed. You have a few options to clean this up. There's the easy way and the *robust* way. Let's look at the easy way first so you can make your boss happy.

## The Question

### Option 1: Instant Gratification

1. You can set the value of the parameter at the same you create it. This will remove one line of code for every parameter you have. For example:

   > ```
   > uPar = .CreateParameter("@PropertyManager", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 60)
   > .Parameters.Append(uPar)
   > .Parameters("@PropertyManager").Value = cmbPropertyManager.Text
   > ```

   Becomes:

   ```
   uPar = .CreateParameter("@PropertyManager", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 60, cmbPropertyManager.Text)
   .Parameters.Append(uPar)
   ```
2. You can one-line the creation and appending of each parameter. This will improve readability and do away with the `uPar` variable entirely. It comes along with slightly more difficult debugging though. Like all things, it's a trade off.

   ```
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PropertyID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , Val(lblPropertyIDValue.Text))
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PropertyManager", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 60, cmbPropertyManager.Text)
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@AddressLine1", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30, txtAddress1.Text)
   .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@AddressLine2", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adLongVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30, txtAddress2.Text)
   ' etc....
   ```

### Option 2: Create A Custom Class

Whenever we work with a class that has a terrible API, some times it makes a lot of sense to wrap that class in one of our own making. Then we get to define the API that we would like to work with ourselves. I won't go into detail about how I would go about this, but I will refer you to several other people who have experienced the same problem you're coming up against. Perhaps their work will inspire your own, or maybe you can down right <s>steal</s> use their code. (It's just a joke, the code I'm linking to is licensed CC-BY-SA. You're totally free to use it.)

- [How do I associate Parameters to Command objects in ADO with VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2931371/3198973)
- [Creating ADODB Parameters on the fly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46312/41243)

## Review

This is Code Review after all, so I'd be remiss not to actually review your code a bit.

- Drop the Hungarian notation. The IDE will tell you what type a variable is. Perhaps it's a company standard, but unless you're working with [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript), this kind of notation is ill advised. The *biggest* reason is because if the type of a variable changes, you either have to change the variable's name or let the notation lie to you. It's unnecessary maintenance and confusion.
- If you *just have* to keep using this notation, at least do it right. It seems that you use `u` as a prefix for all objects. Don't do that. Be specific and explicit. `cmd` is proper for a command, `prm` for a parameter etc. Doing this would force you away from the generic `uPar` and `uCommand` names and into something more descriptive. Win-win.
- I'm a little concerned about how you're keeping track of the state of the connection.

  > ```
  > ' Check For Open Connection
  > If uDBase Is Nothing Then
  >    OpenConnection()
  >    bConnection = True
  > End If
  >
  > ' lots of code
  >
  > If bConnection Then CloseConnection()
  > ```

  This boolean doesn't actually tell you if the connection is open or not. Something could go wrong with the `OpenConnection()` sub. It would be better to actually return a reference to the connection and check its state explicitly.

Comment: Why is the .Parameters.Append come with error

Comment: no accessible append accepts this number of arguments

Comment: You have to define a length for this line. `.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PropertyID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, , Val(lblPropertyIDValue.Text))` should be something like `.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PropertyID", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 50, Val(lblPropertyIDValue.Text))`

Comment: I copied your code, so I'm surprised you're just now seeing this error.

Comment: yeah i Spotted that but it does not seem to fix the problem I am getting the error on the the .Parameters.Append saying no accessible append accepts this number of arguments, im fairly new to this so i appreciate the advice

Comment: Wish I could tell you. Making that change makes it work just fine on my machine.

Comment: okey I must have done something wrong somewhere I will have a look. Thanks for the help