# Implementation of the Access version DBLookup() in VB6

Tags: vb6

I've tried to implement the access function `DBLookup()` in VB6 for a project I'm doing. Does anyone have comments on how well done it is and what could be improved? Take note that the Database connection object `cn` is only valid for a single query, and it's being initialized whenever you call the other public function, `dbConn`.

```
   Public Function cDLookup(TargetField As String, TargetTable As String, cTCondition As String) As String
    'Eigene Implementation von DLookup
    Dim Result As String
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String
    On Error GoTo Fehlerbehandlung

'Zusammenbauen der Query
SQL = "SELECT " & TargetField & " FROM " & TargetTable & " WHERE " & cTCondition

Call dbConn
'Initiate Database connection object cn

rs.Open SQL, cn
If (rs.RecordCount = 1) Then
Result = cleanString(rs.GetString)
Debug.Print ("[DLOOKUP] Erfolgreich Einen Datensatz gefunden und konvertiert. Output: " & Result)

ElseIf (rs.RecordCount > 1) Then
Result = "#ErrRC"
Debug.Print ("[DLOOKUP] Es wurden " & CStr(rs.RecordCount) & " Datensätze statt einem festgestellt. Dies ist nicht erlaubt")

Else
Result = "#ErrGen"
Debug.Print ("[DLOOKUP] Es ist ein Fehler in der Abfrage aufgetreten")
End If
rs.Close

cDLookup = Result
Exit Function
Fehlerbehandlung:
Debug.Print ("[DLOOKUP] Fehler im Ausführen der Prozedur cDLookup()]")
cDLookup = "#Fehler"
Exit Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Potential Memory Leak

At the very beginning you declare an error handler for an undefined line label, but you never use it. This means that if an error occurs, the record set never gets properly closed and released. You should put the clean up code in a "finally" block using the `Exit Function` pattern. (If you look at questions tagged [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) + [error-handling](/questions/tagged/error-handling) you'll find one of my many answers on the topic.)

## SQL Injection

You're concatenating arbitrary user input into a SQL query. This is terribly unsafe. It allows a malicious user virtually full control of your database. I recommend [this Tom Scott video](http://youtu.be/_jKylhJtPmI) for a primer on the subject.

## Style

1. The indentation is all kinds of jacked up.
2. I have no idea why some things are prefixed with a `c`.

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your time and input. I have a few things to adress some of what you said: SQL Injection this is not an issue since the function will be called only from my own program code hereforth. The values it will be called by are strictly preset and numeric, disallowing people to fudge stuff with SQL Injections.

Comment: SQL Injection is *always* an issue. "This will only be called from my code."... No offense meant, but I've heard that before... I get that this is neigh impossible to implement without concatenation, but I would certainly do some sanitation and sanity checking.

Comment: this is code for an internal application at my company that is subject to input only by barcode handscanners. There are really no avenues for someone unauthorized to inject data into the SQL database here. The user executing this code has only insert, update, select and delete rights, only on the proper tables. Every single end user of the application has similar or higher native access in the database.

Comment: Ok... But you can't say you weren't aware of the issue.

Comment: I know of the issue and its definately a huge problem for alot of people, my point was, it just wasn't in this case. I'd let the end users type the sql queries by hand, if I think that they could be bothered.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @RubberDuck's excellent input (which I completely agree with), I have the following concerns:

#### Global Connection

> *Take note that the Database connection object `cn` is only valid for a single query*

Nope, that's not how `ADODB.Connection` works. The reality here is that you have a function that *consumes* a connection that it doesn't *own*, encapsulated by an object that is *global*. Why isn't `dbConn` a function that returns the initialized connection? And if it *initializes a connection*, then why isn't it called `InitializeConnection` or `GetConnection`? And if `cn` is "only valid for a signle query", then why would it ever need to be visible to anything other than the procedure that needs an opened connection?

You're closing the recordset, but not the connection: if `dbConn` starts by closing the previous connection before opening a new one, this means you're leaving a database connection opened for much, much longer than you actually need to, and that's dirty. If `dbConn` doesn't do that, then your connection object simply falls in limbo, and that's outright wrong.

---

#### Call

> ```
> Call dbConn
> 'Initiate Database connection object cn
> ```

That's an obsolete statement. This instruction is completely equivalent:

```
dbConn
'Initiate Database connection object cn
```

It doesn't look like a procedure call, only because of the poor naming of the `dbconn` procedure: if the name started with a verb...

```
InitializeConnection
'Initiate Database connection object cn
```

Why is that comment not *on top* of the instruction it's commenting?

```
'Initiate Database connection object cn
InitializeConnection
```

Now, if `cn` was local as it should be, that comment wouldn't even be needed, as the code would speak for itself:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = InitializeConnection
```

---

#### As New

This is bad:

> ```
> Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
> ```

Why? You might think that this:

```
Dim foo As New Collection
```

Is exactly the same as that:

```
Dim foo As Collection
Set foo = New Collection
```

But it will bite you. What does this code do?

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim foo As New Collection
    foo.Add "bar"
    Set foo = Nothing
    foo.Add "surprise!"
End Sub
```

If you were expecting a *Runtime error 91 - Object reference not set*, you've been bitten. This blows up as expected:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim foo As Collection
    Set foo = New Collection
    foo.Add "bar"
    Set foo = Nothing
    foo.Add "surprise!" 'error 91
End Sub
```

Instead of running the query off the `rs` object with `rs.Open`, *get* a recordset instance from the *connection* with `cn.Execute` instead:

```
Set rs = cn.Execute(SQL)
```

---

#### Magic Return Values

Your function has several ways of "failing". A number of them involve an actual runtime error that the client code must handle. And if my German is correct, 3 of them involve returning a valid string that the client code must check (or treat as valid, and propagate to the UI?). Don't use your return value for that, raise proper errors: the client code should already be handling runtime errors, all you need to do is come up with a way of telling it exactly what went wrong.

An enum works great for that:

```
Public Enum DLookupError
    ErrNoRecordsReturned = vbObjectError + 42
    ErrMultipleRecordsReturned
End Enum
```

Now you can call `Err.Raise DLookupError.ErrNoRecordsReturned, "DLookup", "Es ist ein Fehler in der Abfrage aufgetreten."` to raise a runtime error that can be handled as such, effectively only ever returning an actual string result to your client code when there's such a result to return.

I left out the general "failure" error, since that's simply an error that you should bubble up to the caller.

---

#### Responsibilities

Code that's sprinkled with `rs.Open` calls all over the place, is code with poorly separated concerns. If your application needs to access a database, then you need an object whose responsibility is do to exactly that, so that the rest of the code can work at a higher *abstraction level* and not be bothered with *connections* and *recordsets*.

I've done exactly that in a previous life, and put everything up right here on Code Review, so you can see if you want something similar:

- [Materializing any ADODB Query](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46506/23788)
- [Creating ADODB Parameters on the fly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46312/23788)

The entire function could be pretty much replaced with this (error-handling omitted):

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT " & fieldName & " FROM " & tableName & " WHERE " & predicate

Dim result As String
result = SqlCommand.QuickSelectSingleValue(sql)
```

---

#### Some other considerations

- Parameters are implicitly passed `ByRef`; they can/should be passed `ByVal` instead.
- Prefer `camelCase` for locals (I know VB6 isn't case-sensitive and that's a royal PITA at times); I'd go with `fieldName`, `tableName` and `predicate`.
- You're not validating any of the parameters; an empty string is a valid condition resulting in invalid SQL. Granted that's handled by the error-handling there, but you could *fail early* and avoid sending malformed SQL to the database altogether.

Comment: "You're not validating any of the parameters; an empty string is a valid condition resulting in invalid SQL. Granted that's handled by the error-handling there, but you could fail early and avoid sending malformed SQL to the database altogether." - I've asked this exact question on Stackoverflow before and was told that all I can do is wait for and handle DBerrors properly.

Comment: @Magisch that's because I haven't seen that SO question. If you can avoid a trip to the database, it's usually best to avoid it.

Comment: I've also designed the returns on invalid inputs specifically because the functions calling the DBLookup function are specifically coded for this kind of error typing. Usually I wouldn't do this but im porting old code and I dont want to comb through tons of code to replace everything to fit a different standart.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080189/validate-sql-query-integrity-before-executing-in-vb6 if you want to give it a bash.

Comment: I'm just saying, it's bad practice. And this is where I wish [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com) worked in Visual Studio 6... you could fearlessly refactor that code :-(

Comment: Not only does it not, I only have Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 that crashes every single time I stop debugging or encounter any error while debugging, as well as every single time I try something exotic with it. The problem is the program im porting to is very large (40k+ lines of code) and very much made in the coding style like my function (im still learning so I adapted mainly to what was already there).

Comment: If you want I can tell you a bit more about in in a chatroom, maybe you can help me sort some of this mess out.

Comment: @Magisch I'll be in [VBA Rubberducking](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking) later - feel free to ping me anytime in there (or in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor), but that's the site's main chatroom)